Which computation for permutations on operads is correct?
I am looking at the book simplicial and dendroidal homotopy theory by Heuts and Moerdijk. The permutation axioms for an operad are giving me some trouble. My specific question relates to the following axiom on operads from page 5 of the book. Let $P$ be an operad with a set of colours $C$. Let $p \in P(c_1, ..., c_n; c)$ and $q_i \in P(c_{1_i},..., c_{n_i}; c_i)$. Let $\sigma \in \Sigma_n$ and $\tau_i \in \Sigma_{n_i}$. Then, we have the following axiom:
\begin{equation}
\sigma^*p(\tau^*_{\sigma(1)}q_{\sigma(1)},...,\tau^*_{\sigma(n)}q_{\sigma(n)}) = (\sigma \circ (\tau_1, ..., \tau_n))^*(p(q_1,...,q_n)) \label{1} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
It is then stated this is equivalent to the following two axioms:
$$\sigma^*p(q_{\sigma(1)}, ..., q_{\sigma(n)}) = p(q_1,...,q_n) \label{2} \tag{2}$$
$$p(\tau_1^*q_1, ..., \tau_n^*q_n) = (\tau_1, ..., \tau_n)^*(p(q_1, ..., q_n)) \label{3} \tag{3}$$
Now, going from the first equation to the second pair of equation is a matter of taking $\sigma = \text{id}$ go from equation \eqref{1} to \eqref{2}  and $\tau_1, ..., \tau_n = \text{id}$ to go from \eqref{1} to \eqref{3}.
However, in the other direction, I run into some ambiguity. I feel like both of the following computations are valid:
\begin{align*}
\sigma^*p(\tau^*_{\sigma(1)}q_{\sigma(1)},...,\tau^*_{\sigma(n)}q_{\sigma(n)}) & = (\tau_{\sigma(1)}, ..., \tau_{\sigma(n)})^*(\sigma^*p(q_{\sigma(1)},...,q_{\sigma(n)})) \\
&= (\sigma \circ (\tau_1,..., \tau_n))^*(p(q_1,..., q_n))
\end{align*}
On the other hand, it seems like we could do the following:
\begin{align*}
\sigma^*p(\tau^*_{\sigma(1)}q_{\sigma(1)},...,\tau^*_{\sigma(n)}q_{\sigma(n)}) & = p(\tau_1^*q_1,..., \tau_n^*q_n) \\
& = (\tau_1,..., \tau_n)^*(p(q_1,...,q_n))
\end{align*}
However, this second calculation should be wrong. I just do not see why.

How would you justify the first equation of "on the other hand"?

I thought this is just applying eq (2), the permutation $\sigma$ takes the $i$th entry $\tau_{\sigma(i)}^*q_{\sigma(i)}$ to the $\sigma(i)$th spot. But that is probably the spot, where something is going wrong.

what does $\sigma^*$ mean in (2)? Does it belong to $S(n)$ or $S(k_1+\ldots+k_n)$? In other words, do we apply it only to $p$ or to the given composition?
